# Displaying NextGen Gallery using value from meta not working

Tags: php, plugin-nextgen-gallery

When a user creates a new post there is a meta field on the back end where they can enter the id of the nextgen gallery to display. I want to then display in their post the gallery which corresponds to the id they entered.

When I run the code below $meta echoes as #3 and the gallery shows, so I know that for this post rw_propGallery is set to 3, and that three is the id of an existing gallery.

```
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propGallery', true);
echo $meta;
echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=3]')
```

But if I switch it to

```
echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=$meta]')
```

I get the number 3, and "Gallery not found".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=' . $meta . ']');
```